# Using array variable when building html email in bash

Tags: html, css, bash

So I have a script that builds an html table using inline css so it can be sent as an email.
I'm gathering data into an array variable then trying to populate a table value with that var.

I know I'm close it a quote or way I'm trying to expand the var here.
The array is bk[i], if I just echo bk[1] or bk[2] or whatever it works fine but when I try and do it in the table it shows up as a space.

Here is the second row of the table:

```
    td1="<td>"
    td2="</td>"
   cat head.htm > test.html
    echo "<tbody>" >> test.html
    echo "<tr>" >> test.html
    echo "<th scope=\"row\" style=\"background-color: rgb\(223, 223, 223\); \">"  >> 
    test.html
    echo "Backup</th>" >> test.html
    echo $td1>> test.html
    echo "${bk[1]}" "</td>" >> test.html
    echo $td1>> test.html
    echo ${bk[2]} $td2 >> test.html
    echo $td1>> test.html
    echo ${bk[3]} $td2 >> test.html
    echo $td1>> test.html
    echo ${bk[4]} $td2 >> test.html
    echo $td1>> test.html
    echo "success" $td2 >> test.html
    echo $td1>> test.html
    echo "success" $td2 >> test.html
    echo $td1>> test.html
    echo "success" $td2 >> test.html
    echo $td1>> test.html
    echo "success" $td2 >> test.html
    echo "</tr>" >> test.html
```

I can echo "success" and that works fine but can't seen get get the contents of bk[i] to populate the field.  I'm sure its a single-double q=out or a bracket syntax issue, but can't seem to get it right.

Comment: Where is your array defined? is it, by any chance, defined in a subshell (i.e., `while` loop)? Also, please use groupings instead of redirecting each `echo`!!!

Comment: @shellter, the contents of the array subscript is implicitly evaluated as an arithmetic expression, so you don't need the dollar sign. I have not been able to locate where this is documented in the manual.

Comment: @glennjackman It's in [section 6.7 Arrays of the refence manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays). You'll read: _The subscript is treated as an arithmetic expression that must evaluate to a number._

Answer (score 4):

Where is your array defined?

I'm asking, because it's a very common mistake to do, e.g.,

```
bk=()
cat file | while IFS= read -r line; do
    bk[i++]=$line # or better bk+=( "$line" )
done
```

In this case, the array `bk` is defined in the subshell opened by the pipe, and so is not available anymore after the loop is done...

Instead, you should do this:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    bk+=( "$line" )
done < file
```

In case the feeding comes from a process, and not from a file, use process substitution:

Instead of this:

```
# Do not do this
my_cool_program | while IFS= read -r line; do
    bk+=( "$line" )
done
```

do this:

```
# Please use this
while IFS= read -r line; do
    bk+=( "$line" )
done < <(my_cool_program)
```

**Remark.** This is a bashism (hence not portable to other shells). But your question being tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) this is not a concern for you.

---

Just a remark regarding your style: avoid several redirections (`>` or `>>`); use grouping instead:

```
td1="<td>"
td2="</td>"
{
    cat head.htm
    echo "<tbody>"
    echo "<tr>"
    echo "<th scope=\"row\" style=\"background-color: rgb\(223, 223, 223\); \">"
    echo "Backup</th>"
    echo $td1
    echo "${bk[1]}" "</td>"
    echo $td1
    echo ${bk[2]} $td2
    echo $td1
    echo ${bk[3]} $td2
    echo $td1
    echo ${bk[4]} $td2
    echo $td1
    echo "success" $td2
    echo $td1
    echo "success" $td2
    echo $td1
    echo "success" $td2
    echo $td1
    echo "success" $td2
    echo "</tr>"
} > test.html
```

Avoid lots of `echo`s, use a here document instead:

```
td1="<td>"
td2="</td>"
{
    cat head.htm - <<EOF
<tbody>
<tr>
<th scope="row" style="background-color:rgb(223, 223, 223);">Backup</th>
$td1${bk[1]}$td2
$td1${bk[2]}$td2
$td1${bk[3]}$td2
$td1${bk[4]}$td2
${td1}success$td2
${td1}success$td2
${td1}success$td2
${td1}success$td2
</tr>
EOF
} > test.html
```

Isn't that much better? Like this, the file will be opened once, whereas in the snippet you gave, the file is reoponed many times.

And look, it works:

```
gniourf@somewhere$ bk=(zero one two three four)
gniourf@somewhere$ td1="<td>"; td2="</td>"
gniourf@somewhere$ {
>     cat head.htm - <<EOF
> <tbody>
> <tr>
> <th scope="row" style="background-color:rgb(223, 223, 223);">Backup</th>
> $td1${bk[1]}$td2
> $td1${bk[2]}$td2
> $td1${bk[3]}$td2
> $td1${bk[4]}$td2
> ${td1}success$td2
> ${td1}success$td2
> ${td1}success$td2
> ${td1}success$td2
> </tr>
> EOF
> } > test.html
gniourf@somewhere$ cat test.html
<tbody>
<tr>
<th scope="row" style="background-color:rgb(223, 223, 223);">Backup</th>
<td>one</td>
<td>two</td>
<td>three</td>
<td>four</td>
<td>success</td>
<td>success</td>
<td>success</td>
<td>success</td>
</tr>
gniourf@somewhere$
```

Yay.

Comment: My Array is defined before I start populating the table so it's full of values when I go into building the html(I have grown to really hate inline css) Thanks for the feedback, I'll try this out.

Comment: @geezer Then it should work. Please look at the last part of my answer.

Comment: OK cool, I was defining it in a loop and now works much better with this method - new to building html with bash.  Thanks for the guidance!